# ggplot2 running for minutes without plotting

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am attempting to plot the below vector, but when I run the function, it just continues to run and does not plot. I have waited 5 minutes before I feel uncomfortable and click stop in the console. Wondering what is going on. Up until this point I have had no trouble. While I am using `facet_wrap` with seven variables - there are only 56 rows and 4 columns so it doesn't make sense why it would take so long.

See below `dput()` of my vector:

```
structure(list(`data_2021_v2$member_casual` = c("casual", "member", 
"casual", "member", "casual", "member", "casual", "member", "casual", 
"member", "casual", "member", "casual", "member", "casual", "member", 
"casual", "member", "casual", "member", "casual", "member", "casual", 
"member", "casual", "member", "casual", "member", "casual", "member", 
"casual", "member", "casual", "member", "casual", "member", "casual", 
"member", "casual", "member", "casual", "member", "casual", "member", 
"casual", "member", "casual", "member", "casual", "member", "casual", 
"member", "casual", "member", "casual", "member"), `data_2021_v2$time_of_day` = c(1, 
1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4), `data_2021_v2$day_of_week` = c("Friday", 
"Friday", "Friday", "Friday", "Friday", "Friday", "Friday", "Friday", 
"Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Monday", 
"Monday", "Saturday", "Saturday", "Saturday", "Saturday", "Saturday", 
"Saturday", "Saturday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", 
"Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Thursday", 
"Thursday", "Thursday", "Thursday", "Thursday", "Thursday", "Thursday", 
"Thursday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", 
"Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", 
"Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday"
), `data_2021_v2$ride_length` = c(840, 584, 686, 526, 1023, 521, 
916, 610, 895, 545, 697, 530, 1125, 515, 971, 584, 906, 610, 
900, 594, 1194, 666, 1102, 673, 928, 590, 1002, 606, 1225, 676, 
1171, 670, 783, 556, 646, 521, 903, 495, 871, 590, 820, 544, 
652, 530, 962, 499, 891, 584, 814, 566, 647, 531, 920, 496, 874, 
591)), row.names = c(NA, -56L), class = "data.frame")
```

And below is the function I am using to plot:

```
ggplot(toddowrlmed, aes(factor(`data_2021_v2$time_of_day`, level=c(2,3,4,1)),
                        `data_2021_v2$ride_length`, fill=`data_2021_v2$member_casual`)) +
  facet_wrap(data_2021_v2$day_of_week) +
  geom_col(position = 'dodge')
```

And my `sessionInfo()`:

```
    R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    
system code page: 65001

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] lubridate_1.8.0 forcats_0.5.1   stringr_1.4.0   dplyr_1.0.7     purrr_0.3.4     readr_2.1.2     tidyr_1.2.0    
 [8] tibble_3.1.6    ggplot2_3.3.5   tidyverse_1.3.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.8       cellranger_1.1.0 pillar_1.7.0     compiler_4.1.2   dbplyr_2.1.1     tools_4.1.2     
 [7] digest_0.6.29    bit_4.0.4        jsonlite_1.7.3   lifecycle_1.0.1  gtable_0.3.0     pkgconfig_2.0.3 
[13] rlang_1.0.1      reprex_2.0.1     rstudioapi_0.13  DBI_1.1.2        cli_3.1.1        parallel_4.1.2  
[19] haven_2.4.3      xml2_1.3.3       withr_2.4.3      httr_1.4.2       fs_1.5.2         generics_0.1.2  
[25] vctrs_0.3.8      hms_1.1.1        bit64_4.0.5      grid_4.1.2       tidyselect_1.1.1 glue_1.6.1      
[31] R6_2.5.1         fansi_1.0.2      readxl_1.3.1     vroom_1.5.7      farver_2.1.0     tzdb_0.2.0      
[37] modelr_0.1.8     magrittr_2.0.2   backports_1.4.1  scales_1.1.1     ellipsis_0.3.2   rvest_1.0.2     
[43] assertthat_0.2.1 colorspace_2.0-2 labeling_0.4.2   utf8_1.2.2       stringi_1.7.6    munsell_0.5.0   
[49] broom_0.7.12     crayon_1.4.2
```

My laptop is brand new and relatively powerful with an intel i7 and 16GB ram, so I can't imagine its a "processing power" issue. Thank you.

Comment: I have never seen a data frame with "$" in the column names, I would fix that first.  Then I don't believe this is correct; "aes(factor(`data$time_of_day`...", double check your variables.  Also `facet_wrap(data_2021_v2$day_of_week)` might be the issue.

Comment: The vector was created from an `aggregate` function, which is why `$` is in the column name. I have successfully plotted similar vectors with `$` in the column name that I have created the same way, from the same larger `df`. I'm also assuming the `facet_wrap` is the issue, but I can't understand why.

Comment: Try adding a pair of "`" around the variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `facet_wrap()` call does not look correct, and you have some difficult-to-work-with column names. I named your dput structure `dat`, and gave it column names, and ran your plot with the facet_wrap correction, like this:

```
colnames(dat) = c("member_casual", "time_of_day", "day_of_week", "ride_length")

ggplot(dat, aes(factor(time_of_day, level=c(2,3,4,1)),
                ride_length,
                fill=member_casual)) +
  facet_wrap(~day_of_week) +
  geom_col(position = 'dodge')
```

Comment: This worked. I first added `~` which I had forgot and tried to run it, but it returned this error `Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "PANEL", value = c(3L, 7L, 5L, 5L,  : 
  replacement has 5594452 rows, data has 56`. I then changed my column names and it ran just fine. I'm still curious as to why the original function just continued to run without displaying an error.

Comment: You didn't have backticks around the variable name in the `facet_wrap()` call. As others have said it's really dangerous to have those column names so your life will get much easier if you change them.